# HTTP post callback in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've been learning Angular 4 recently and used the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6).

In the Hero service the addHero method is configured using a .pipe function, copied below:

```
/** POST: add a new hero to the server */
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
        tap((hero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${hero.id}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
    );
}
```

This is all fine - now the component can call this.heroService(heroObject). The issue I am having, however, is what happens when it goes wrong. Yes, the catchError inside the pipe handles it, however to me it seems that the component has no idea what's going on. What if the there's a 404 and the hero is never added? In the component the hero is added via:

```
add(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
        .subscribe(hero => {
            this.heroes.push(hero);
        });
}
```

To me, it seems that if an error occurred, this.heroes.push(hero) would still activate, and we'd get a hero added incorrectly to the component's hero array. How could I configure it so that on a successful post, this.heroes.push(hero) is done, and in the case, an error is thrown (4xx, 5xx etc.), an alert (for simplicity) is instead displayed?

Comment: That is just a sample to demonstrate the concepts. You are required to handle corresponding events as you intend. Say, in case of error, user needs to be informed, via an alert message or alert styles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
add(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
        .subscribe(hero => {
            this.heroes.push(hero);
        }, error => {
            alert("Failed to get the hero.");
        });
}
```

In the preceding code segment, the second parameter of the `subscribe` method takes the error event handler. And the first parameter will only be called on the successful completion (200 Ok) of the request. So, there is no chance of getting a Hero added incorrectly.

Comment: To add to this, the `subscribe` method can receive up to three parameters: a `next` function, an `error` function and a `complete` function. For Http requests in particular, `next` is called on a successful request, `error` is called on an error and `complete` is called after the `next` function.

See also: [ReactiveX docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Good to see that you're saying something similar to what I've already tried. At least it means I was down the right path.
However, the error is still not filtering its way back. I think the reason for that is the first block of code that seems to be handling the error does not let the error filter back out. As the guide describes it:
"The following handleError() method reports the error and then returns an innocuous result so that the application keeps working."
Any way to keep the functionality of handleError but still make it filter out?